# How do I format a regex that includes a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that works fine if I hard-code a value such as "foo":

```
/foo/
```

But what if "foo" is a variable? How to I write the regex for that? For example:

```
var bar = "foo";
```

I can't get `/bar/` to work. How can I format this to work when "bar" is a variable?

Comment: Can you show exactly how you're using these? Both what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Can your variable contain special regex variable like `? OR * OR + OR { OR } OR ( OR ) OR [ OR ]` etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use new RegExp like this:

```
var bar = "foo",
    re = new RegExp(bar)

bar.match(re) //returns ["foo"]
```

Comment: You might need to use something like [`preg_quote`](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/) if you have hard coded characters that are reserved by regex (eg. `[`, `]`, `.`, `?`, `*`, `+`, `(` and `)`) as these would otherwise work as their regex equivilant. `got milk?` would for example allow `got milz` (as the last `k` is optional) and `r+a` would allow `rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrra`.